# How to run a nonlinear repeated measure multilevel regression?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, nonlinear-regression

I'm working with a colleague on a project that requires analysis a fair bit beyond my expertise.

**Background** We are looking at recall of events in films. We broke down the film by Events and by shots (unbroken camera recording) within each event. There are 5 films being looked at. Each film has a different number of Events, and each Event has a different number of shots within the Event. Recall is measured per shot (1 they recalled it, 0 they didn't), with an average across all participants per shot.

**Hypothesis** Our hypothesis is that participants will recall the beginning and end of events sig. more than middle events (and that plot-important information was placed at those locations, but that is a different part).

**Problem** I was able to make graphs (below) from out data, highlighting the quadratic line of best fit for each Event (though it is scaled based on maximum number of Shots overall, rather than per Event. The graphs appear to support our hypothesis. However, I'm having great trouble in actually running the analysis.

[image: Trend of Recall by ShotWithinEvent, across multiple Events]
**Data** Our data looks something like this:

```
 Event   Shot  EventShots MeanAcc   
   1       1    2        .07
   1       2    2        .57
   2       1    1        .63
   3       1    29       .63
   3       2    29       .60
   3       3    29       .27
   3       4    29       .23
   3       5    29       .27
   3       6    29       .20
   3       7    29       .13
   3       8    29       .20
   3       9    29       .20
   3      10    29       .23
   3      11    29       .23
   3      12    29       .40
```

So, Shot (ShotwithEvent) is nested inside of Event and the total number of shots per event changes.

**R** I've been trying to use **lmer** and **nlme** but I'm having difficulty figuring out the exact syntax I need to get the appropriate results. I've tried as follows (billy is the film data frame).

```
    model <- lmer(billy$MeanAcc ~ poly(billy$ShotWithinEvent, 2, raw=TRUE) 
             + (billy$Event|billy$ShotWithinEvent), data=billy)
```

But that gives me this error:

```
    Warning message:
    In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv, 
    Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.28082 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

This one appears to work without error, but doesn't seem to give me any useful data

```
> model <- lmer(billy$MeanAcc ~ billy$ShotWithinEvent + (1|billy$Event), 
  data=billy)
> model

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: billy$MeanAcc ~ billy$ShotWithinEvent + (1 | billy$Event)
Data: billy
REML criterion at convergence: -279.3091
Random effects:
Groups      Name        Std.Dev.
billy$Event (Intercept) 0.06212 
Residual                0.19957 
Number of obs: 889, groups:  billy$Event, 50
Fixed Effects:
      (Intercept)  billy$ShotWithinEvent  
        0.4317315             -0.0001141
```

So, I'm kinda lost on what I need to do to appropriately test the nonlinear relationship of MeanAcc on ShotswithEvents (with unequal values), nested with Events. Any help would be appreciated!

Clarify: There were 30 participants who all saw all 5 films.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what is going on in this study? Who is looking at these films - the participants? How many participants are there?  Is each participant looking at each of the 5 films?

Comment: You could consider that events are nested in films if your outcome variable is "average recall per shot across all participants who watched the shot corresponding to an event within a movie".  Each event gives rise to repeated outcome values - one per shot within event.  If you do that, though, the outcome variable is shot-specific and the predictor variable is event-specific, since it is expressed as the "number of shots per event".  Is that what you really want?

Comment: I didn't design the experiment, I joined and started helping after data was collected. 

I believe that is what we are doing. The films are being analyzed independently. But it's Film > Event > Shots.

We aren't concerned so much about the number of shots, but Accuracy as a function of shot position within an event. The hypothesis is that accuracy will be higher at the beginning and end of event, regardless of total number of shots. As can be seen in the graphs I linked above.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications, Michael! The complicating factor is that your outcome variable values are averaged across all participants for every shot. So you have dependency of the outcome values not just within the same event but also across events if all participants watch all the films. If different sets of participants watch different films, that would not be an issue. So understanding who watched what films is key. Also, how is shot position assessed within a shot? Is is just a number keeping track of the sequencing of the shots (e.g., first shot, second shot, third shot, etc.)

Comment: We have the individual accuracy scores for each participant (coded as 1 or 0). Though I don't know if participant number is consistent across films. 

The data that I have now for each film is broken down by shots. Each row represents a single shot starting from time 00:00 to the end of the film. Each row has the sequential shot number (1-900), time start/stop, the event number, the shot number within the event (variable as it resets for each event), a column for each participant's accuracy, and a mean accuracy across all p's for that shot.